# how to access event controls inside asp repeater control

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am having form which allows user to update their profile and contact information.I have created this form using asp:repeater control inside a div tag .I am having 4 div tags inside that having repeater control which contains other controls such as text boxes and drop down list. I just want to know,how can i access controls inside repeater control. I want if the user changes the value of the control (1), I get the value and assign it to another control (2). look at the picture

[image]

Comment: Do you intend to do this with JavaScript? Or postbacks?

Comment: i want to do it with c# in code behind